# How can I install indicator-session without pulling in extra packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

I removed `indicator-session` by accident. Now, when I try to install it again through apt-get I get this.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  indicator-session libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1
  libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xkb1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 session-migration signon-keyring-extension
  signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon unity-settings-daemon
```

These packages *weren't* installed before. How do I install `indicator-session` back without installing all these extra packages?

Comment: To bring you the most precise answer, could you give me the content (via pastebin) of your apt log file (`/var/log/apt/term.log`), if this file is empty you could look in the `/var/log/apt/ folder`; you'll find old log files. Best regards, Nicolas

Comment: Looks like the system is trying to pull in Unity 8's packages. Did you try with `--no-recommends`?

Comment: Thanks @RolandiXor, `--no-install-recommends` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [these](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/how-can-i-install-indicator-session-without-pulling-in-extra-packages?noredirect=1#comment1797_1059) [comments](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/how-can-i-install-indicator-session-without-pulling-in-extra-packages?noredirect=1#comment1964_1059), using

```
--no-install-recommends
```

prevents the extra packages from installing.